# Partial pivoting in row reduction

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

I have a large $m \times 2m$ numerical matrix which I obtained from [`NullSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html). I expect that the matrix is equivalent under row operations to a sparse matrix with small integer values.

However, when I [`RowReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowReduce.html), the matrix becomes ill-conditioned because it tries to pivot on very small values which should be zero up to numerical errors. <strike>Partial pivoting is the algorithm which pivots on the largest entry of a row at each step in row reduction, which would prevent the matrix from becoming ill-conditioned.</strike>

Is there an implementation of partial pivoting in *Mathematica*?

---

Edit 1: Here is some Mathematica code to generate examples of this kind.

```
(*Generate a random sparse integer matrix of size m x 2m*)
m = 20;
intmat = 
 SparseArray[
  Flatten[Table[{j, RandomInteger[{1, 2 m}]} -> 
     RandomChoice[{-1, 1}], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, m}]]]

(*Multiply on the left by a random real unit determinant matrix. 
This preserves the row span but obscures the sparse integer 
representation*)

realmat = 
  Module[{randommat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, m}]}, 
    randommat/Abs[Det[randommat]]^(1/m)] . intmat;

(*To recover an integer representation, row reduce. The row reduction
 agrees with the row reduction of the original integer matrix, as 
expected*)

Rationalize[Chop[RowReduce[realmat]]] // MatrixForm

RowReduce[intmat] // MatrixForm

(*Introduce small numerical errors, and then observe that the row 
reduction is quite bad*)

approxmat = RandomReal[{-2*10^-10, 2*10^-10}, {m, 2 m}] + realmat;

Rationalize[Chop[RowReduce[approxmat]]] // MatrixForm

(*However, this is fixed by testing for zeroes with a high enough 
tolerance*)

Rationalize[
  Chop[RowReduce[approxmat, ZeroTest -> (Chop[#1, 10^-8] == 0 &)], 
   10^-8], 10^-7] // MatrixForm
```

So [`ZeroTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZeroTest.html) fixes this problem perfectly for small matrices. However, try the same approximate example above with m=500. I find that the errors accumulate over the course of [`RowReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowReduce.html), requiring a larger and larger tolerance for [`ZeroTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZeroTest.html). In my case, my matrix has around $m=2000$. (Beware: running [`RowReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowReduce.html) with [`ZeroTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZeroTest.html) for $m=2000$ takes about 10 minutes on my 16 core machine.) For $m$ large enough, there is no value of the tolerance which gives the correct answer, once the accumulated errors become larger than the smallest nonzero values of the real matrix.

In my case, the solution will be to re-generate the original data at higher precision. This should allow me to get a clear separation between the size of the errors (even as they accumulate) and the smallest nonzero values. Even though this method is computationally costly, I'm lucky that I have this option at all.

I wonder if there would be any more stable way to analyze large real matrices that are hiding simple integer information. In the scenario where the uncertainties in the data are irreducible, such a stable analysis would be required.

Comment: Can you use `Chop` to remove the negligible values prior to `RowReduce`?

Comment: RowReduce has an option "ZeroTest". Look it up in the help.

Comment: **Is there an implementation of partial pivoting in Mathematica?** Could you make a MWE? I would be very surprised if Mathematica does not do this automatically.  Yes, it does. Looking at help/implementation notes, it says  **RowReduce use Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting** So I think you have something else going on.

Comment: Ate these computations done with exact integer arithmetic? Or with approximate values. I would expect different behavior for these cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The original matrix is filled with nonzero numerical complex numbers. The rows are orthogonal and normalized. @Nasser, thank you for pointing that out. I think you are right that something else must be going on. Daniel, I tried ZeroTest, and it didn't work in the sense that I still have rows that look like (0,0,1,...,epsilon^-1,...) where epsilon is the value I chose for zerotest.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau A mental model for the data is that you take a fairly sparse integer matrix $A$ of size $m \times 2m$ and multiply on the left by a random invertible real matrix $B$. I start with the matrix product $BA$ and am trying to recover the sparse integer matrix $A$. I've been trying to do this with row reduction and Rationalize, but the numerical nature of the problem is getting in the way somehow.

Comment: You might want to post a smallish example with known solution, as well as code you have tried. I suspect this to be a hard problem but maybe someone will have an idea once they see what you’ve done thus far.

Comment: Also do you know in advance how the rows were orthonormalized? If by Gram-Schmidt, there might be a possibility of undoing the operations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I've added code for generating random examples of this phenomenon. Regarding orthonormalization, I originally got my matrix as a nullspace, so whichever algorithm it used is responsible for the orthonormlization. Regardless, I have the option of generating higher precision data, which should solve this problem in my case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?:

```
tol = Sqrt[Max[Abs[approxmat - realmat]]]
{q, r} = QRDecomposition[approxmat];
RowReduce[r, Tolerance -> tol] //
  Rationalize[#, tol] & //
   MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- The tolerance should depend on the noise, imo; `Sqrt[]` may be overaggressive (not sure, though).
- `r` is equal to `q . approxmat`; multiplying by `q`, which is invertible (orthogonal), preserves row-equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try QR and see how it goes. 

Unfortunately in my actual application, I don't have a way to determine precisely how large the errors are. In other words, I don't have access to intmat or realmat, just approxmat, since the data comes with some amount of uncertainty/error.

Comment: @DanielLongenecker "I don't have a way to determine precisely how large the errors are" -- maybe you can guess or approximate the tolerance. As I understand the problem, you're going to have to do it no matter what approach you take, no? You picked `2*10^-10` in the question -- maybe that was a reasonable choice. If you lower the tolerance too much, you get large-term fractions for numbers close integers from `Rationalize` and small nonzero numbers from `Chop`.